# May a compiler report errors on unknown attributes? Even with scope?

Tags: c++, attributes, c++11

In N3291 *"7.6.1.(3/5) Attribute Syntax and semantics [decl.attr.grammar]"* concerning how **attributes** are written in source code I read

> The use of an *attribute-scoped-token* is conditionally-supported, with
>    implementation-defined behavior.

and

> For an *attribute-token* not specified in this International Standard, the behavior is implementation-defined.

Does this mean, that attribute specifications like

```
[[ dllexport ]]
[[ hiding ]]
[[ unused ]]
[[ vendor::attrib ]]
```

may be complained about by a *standard conforming compiler*? So, it **could report an error** and stop compilation?

I would have hoped that a compiler **should ignore** attributes that it does not know how to handle them. Ok, that might be dangerous, because typos in attributes may be overlooked, for example `[[ noretrun ]]` or `[[ carrys_dependencie ]]` :-)

But especially namespaces would help here, right? When I compile `[[ gcc::mips ]]` on an *Microsoft compiler* that one should be able to ignore that and not reject it, right?

Comment: +1, and -1 to the Standard for "conditionally supported" BS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++17 adds an explicit statement that attributes not recognized by an implementation are to be ignored. Before C++17, all attribute behavior was implementation defined, so the implementation could do anything.

Part of the purpose of the attribute specification is so that compiler makers will stop cluttering the language up with special syntax and keywords. To give them a single grammar for specifying these things. It is a way to associate a compiler-defined string with a particular object or definition.

Comment: ...except for stopping with an error message, of course (*because* no-one supports it, yet) ;-). Ok, the grammar is defined now, but what is the big difference between stopping because of *"I do not know the attribute name"* and stopping because of *"your strange attribute syntax confused me"* by the compilers. I thought it was designed to be an **extendable system**, but if compilers stop on something unknown, this is not a good place for extensions. I guess my assumption was wrong?

Comment: @towi you could always complain to your compilre developer that it should emit a warning instead of stopping compilation since the syntax is defined and the vendor may choose the behaviour he likes. The advantage of a defined syntax is that he can be sure to have matched an attribute and not some syntax error.

Comment: I see. So you say that "*implementation defined behavior"* translates  roughly to "*should emit diagnostics but continues compiling"*. But to make it a bit easier for the not-quite-perfect-yet compilers it is also "allowed" to stop?

Comment: @towi: No; "implementation defined behavior" translates to "does whatever the compiler wants". You can argue what a compiler _ought_ to do, but the specification says nothing about what the compiler _will_ do. And therefore, if the compiler wants to stop, then it will. If the compiler wants to emit a warning, that's fine too.

Comment: @Nicol: Yes, sure. But I what should a teacher tell his students about this feature, then? I could not tell people, "use it" with the explanation "the compiler can what it want". I'd say we need a *"Good Practice Rule"*, so for teaching one may say "use it carefully, for (this and that) reason". For now I summarize to "don't use it", and when we have compilers that support it we can derive a "use it by (this and that) rule, but be careful".

Comment: @towi: Since no compilers support the syntax as of yet, you should tell your students not to use it if they want their code to actually compile. You can't have a "Good Practice Rule" until there is actual practice. So until multiple compilers support it, all you have to go on is the specification.

Comment: cppreference says: "All attributes unknown to an implementation are ignored without causing an error. (since C++17)"

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> [[ vendor::attrib ]]
> ```
>
> may be complained about by a standard conforming compiler?

Yes, especially this one *should* be complained about a standard conforming compiler that doesn't support the conditionally supported behavior (a diagnostic message is required).

However, I'm not sure about the others. The standard contains also this:

> ...  If an attribute-speciﬁer-seq  that appertains to some entity or
>   statement contains an attribute that is not allowed to apply to that
>   entity or statement, the program is ill-formed. ...

I believe it could be read permissively, that only those attributes that surely are in violation of the rule make the program ill-formed (ie. the ones that the compiler doesn't know don't), however, I'm not quite sure. Anyway, using implementation-defined behavior does not make the program ill-formed.

Currently, [gcc accepts unknown attributes with a warning](http://ideone.com/fQdme), so I believe it will work like that with the new syntax, too.

Comment: Ok, for `[[ vendor::attrib ]]` I now see a difference between a) the whole attribute-scoping may not be supported by the compiler (resulting in an error) and b) the compiler supports the scoping itself, but `vendor` is an unknown scope. I do not like that "conditionally-support" but understand it now. This leaves open if a compiler is allowed to stop-with-error on an unknown non-scoped attribute. That `gcc` only warns is exactly my point: What if I rely on my gcc-practice that the compiler ignores unknown attributes safely? I will write non-portable code without knowing it. Bad, I think.

Answer (score 0):

**Since C++17**: All attributes unknown to an implementation are ignored without causing an error. Compiler can only emit a warning.

**Before C++17**: Compiler can do anything.