# Suggestions for using attributes beyond [[noreturn]]?

Tags: c++11, attributes, custom-attributes

Coming from the discussions about the *use of vendor specific attributes* in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7414829/472245) I asked myself, **"what rules should we tell people for using attributes that are not listed in the standard"**?

The two attributes that are defined are `[[ noreturn ]]` and `[[ carries_dependencies ]]`. The standard leaves open how compilers should react on unknown attributes -- thus, by the standard they may stop with an error message. This is not what e.g. *GCC* does, it emits a warning and continues. This is probably a behavior to be expected by the most-common compilers. For this reason I would have like to read a "should" in the standard, but we don't have it.

The paper N2553 brings up flexible attributes. It lists further attributes used by GCC (
`unused`, `weak`) and MSVC (`dllimport`). for OpenMP, the widely supported parallelizing framework, scoped attributes are suggested, eg. `omp::for(clause, clause)`, `omp::parallel(clause,clause)`. So, it is very likely that we will se some vendor specific attributes very soon after they support the syntax at all, indeed.

**Therefore, when we now go "out in the world" and tell people about C++11, what should the advice be about using attributes?**

- Only use `noreturn` and `carries_dependencies`
- Use your compilers *old syntax* instead, eg. `__attribute__((noreturn))` and define a macro when you port the code (the current situation)
- Use those attributes your favorite compiler supports freely, knowing this code might not be portable to another standard-conforming compiler, because if the standard allows a compiler to stop with an error, you have to consider this will happen. This sounds a bit like advocating writing non-portable code.
- Or, my guess, expect the most-used compilers to *warn* about unknown attributes, so you can use vendor-specific attributes, keeping in mind that in rare cases you may get problems.

Note the slight difference in the last two bullet-items. While both say "use those attributes you need", item3's message is "do not care about other compilers", while item4 implicitly rephrases the standard texts "implementation defined behavior" to "the compiler *should* emit a diagnostic message".

**What could be the suggestion for an upcoming *Best Practice* here?**

Comment: This question is purely speculative. It is about a feature that is barely implemented, asks about how one might want to view it across compilers that don't implement it yet. There are no _actual_ facts for any answer to be based on; any answers would be sheer speculation.

Comment: I disagree. I ask about the intention of the standard designers and guidance as an ambassador for the upcoming standard.

Comment: @towi: You're asking about how to cope with various implementations. Those implementations *do not exist*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice — the only one that is reasonably portable in practical terms, never mind ambiguity in the Standard — is to use macros. It will be many years before we can forget about compilers that don't support attributes.

The number of compilers and the number of custom `__keywords__` defined by those compilers will always be increasing, and it makes sense for the language to define a way to contain the damage. It doesn't need to revolutionize the way people write unportable code, or make unportable code portable (although standard attributes do that). There is a benefit simply to giving caffeine-addled compiler backend engineers a sandbox for when they want to extend the grammar.

It is a bit alarming, though, that no attribute tokens are reserved to the implementation, or to the language besides the ones currently standard. So there will be trouble when they decide to standardize more of them.